# How to create customized locator in Selenium with large value of id and class name attributes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Can someone help me with how to generate Xpath with the below html snippet.
I am struggling to make xpath for it , as the id ,class to are big ...please help how to generate Xpath for this.

```
<input class="js-text-full text-full form-text required" data-drupal-selector="edit-page-content-0-subform-page-layout-content-0-subform-slot-1-0-subform-slot-content-form-inline-entity-form-module-type-content-0-subform-module-a-content-0-subform-large-composite-image-carousel-0-subform-large-composite-images-0-subform-header-text-0-subform-header-text-header-text-lines-0-subform-header-text-line-text-items-0-subform-text-items-items-0-subform-text-styled-text-0-value" type="text" id="edit-page-content-0-subform-page-layout-content-0-subform-slot-1-0-subform-slot-content-form-inline-entity-form-module-type-content-0-subform-module-a-content-0-subform-large-composite-image-carousel-0-subform-large-composite-images-0-subform-header-text-0-subform-header-text-header-text-lines-0-subform-header-text-line-text-items-0-subform-text-items-items-0-subform-text-styled-text-0-value--5OtB_Vbe-qw" name="page_content[0][subform][page_layout_content][0][subform][slot_1][0][subform][slot_content][form][inline_entity_form][module_type_content][0][subform][module_a_content][0][subform][large_composite_image_carousel][0][subform][large_composite_images][0][subform][header_text][0][subform][header_text__header_text_lines][0][subform][header_text_line__text_items][0][subform][text_items__items][0][subform][text_styled_text][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generate Xpath for this"?

Comment: Sorry my bad ..I meant by saying how to create customise Xpath.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a chunk of html, that the `<input>` tag in the question is part of that html and you want to find the xpath of this `<input>` in that html? If that's the case, you may need to paste a representative sample of that html. It's difficult, or impossible, to generate a "universal" xpath.

Answer (score 1):

if your class is unique, you can just use it:

```
//input[@class="js-text-full text-full form-text required"]
```

if you think class name is too long you can go for contains and mention partial matching string:

```
//input[contains(@class,"form-text required")]
```

if your class is not unique you can try using it with combination of other attributes like type

```
//input[contains(@class,"form-text required") and @type="text"]
```

Or you can use it with the combination of class name and partial matching id:

```
//input[@class="js-text-full text-full form-text required" and contains(@id,"edit-page-content")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath //input[@class="js-text-full text-full form-text required"]

if its not working pls share your Html elements here

Comment: with class it doesn't work, because the class name have spaces.

Comment: DOES NOT MATTER IF CLASS NAME HAVING SPACES YOU JUST COPY ELEMENT BY INSPECTING ON BROWSER AND USE IT

Answer (score 0):

Larger value of *id* or *class name* shouldn't be a barrier when you construct logical [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). It's an `<input>` element and possibly moving forward you'd interact with the element and as the element is a dynamic element, so you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and `cssSelector`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.js-text-full.text-full.form-text.required[data-drupal-selector^='edit-page-content'][maxlength='255'][placeholder]"))).click()
  ```
- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='js-text-full text-full form-text required' and starts-with(@data-drupal-selector, 'edit-page-content')][@placeholder and @maxlength='255']")));
  ```